# Parsing access log data to fit DB format

Tags: python, mysql, perl, bash

I have a web access CSV file with some statistics that looks like this (usually about 20K records but this is an example with only 6 records):

```
servlet name, HTTP RC, response time, request timestamp
/servlet_A,200,3,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:12 +0000]
/servlet_B,302,10,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:12 +0000]
/servlet_C,200,17,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:12 +0000]
/servlet_A,200,30,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:15 +0000]
/servlet_B,302,16,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:15 +0000]
/servlet_C,200,11,[10/Nov/2013:11:00:15 +0000]
```

I need to parse it to the following format:

```
servlet name, requests count with latency in range 0-5, latency range 6-10, latency range 11-15, ...., latency range 196-200, HTTP 200 count, HTTP 302 count
servlet_A,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,....,2,0
servlet_B,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,....,0,2
servlet_C,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,....,2,0
```

The files are located on a CentOS based server with tools like Perl, Python, Bash. The output file would be used to load into a 3rd party MySQL DB which I don't have access to.

I tried writing this in bash but my math was a bit off, I tried placing the latency count using division by 5, e.g. latency = 11 and 11 / 5 = 2.2 and round upwards. Meaning that an increment by 1 should be added to the 3rd spot, but I had problems to parse it properly.

Maybe there are other options at all to perform this (using a locally built DB and exporting the file) or some other options I'm now aware off so any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: you can import your data into database if you feel more comfortable with sql queries?

Comment: That's the problem, I can't. It's a 3rd party DB which I don't have access to, and it requires to receive the data for import in the way I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and ugly for one-off data conversion and does not follow any conventions of good coding practices :-). Assuming your data is in `data.txt`. Does not output any header.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

# Sub-program to calculate latency counts for number range
# params: key, latency lower limit, latency upper limit
sub latencyCounts {
  $latency_total = 0;
  for ($i = $_[1]; $i <= $_[2]; $i++) {
    $latency_total += $latency_counts{$_[0]}[$i];  
  }
  return $latency_total;
}

# parse file and add data to arrays
open (FOO, "< data.txt");
while (<FOO>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^\/(.+),(\d{3}),(\d+),\[.+\]$/) {
    $httpcode_counts{$1}[$2]++;
    $latency_counts{$1}[$3]++;
  }
}
close (FOO);

# calculate and output totals
foreach (sort keys %httpcode_counts) {
  $key = $_;
  printf ("%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,...,%d,%d\n",
      $key,
      latencyCounts($key, 0, 5),
      latencyCounts($key, 6, 10),
      latencyCounts($key, 11, 195),
      latencyCounts($key, 196, 200),
      $httpcode_counts{$key}[200],
      $httpcode_counts{$key}[302]);
}

exit;
```

Someone could probably make the same results in less than half the code...?

Comment: Thanks Simo A. The `...` I added were just to shorten the post. Eventually the output file should contain the servlet name (e.g. servlet_A), 40 fields of ranges (0-5, 6-10 .... 196-200) and two additional fields of HTTP response codes.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it was evident that you used `...` to shorten your post - that is what I did to shorten my code as well. I am sure you can modify the code to suit your exact needs, since all the required functionality is in place already. Please mark my answer as accepted if you find it a correct answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry Simo A. - I believe that there's a more optimal way rather than writing manually each and every range. In example, if the ranges would go up to 1000, it mean I'll need to write 200 lines manually, which is, I believe, a bad solution :)

Comment: Yes, this was a quick and dirty solution to get you into the right direction :-). What you need to do is to add a simple for-loop to get the counts for each range. That way you can avoid typing each range manually.